# how to do json parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am using  json parsing in my application
and this is my json data is as follow :

{"response" :
 {"success":false,"error":
{"code":7,"description":"You are not logged in"}}}

and i want description means "You are not logged in" i my string
so how can i do that 
please help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the blog post with sample code and step by step parsing of JSON.

http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/

http://pessoal.org/blog/2008/12/12/iphone-sdk-parsing-json-data/

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 2):

We're using CJSONDeserializer ([TouchJSON library](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)) in the iPhone app being developed at work.

Just use the following method:

```
NSDictionary * dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:data error:&error];
```

where data is of type NSData *. It will convert the JSON string into a dictionary so you could get the value of description as follows:

```
[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"error"] objectForKey:@"description"];
```

Comment: thanks for your  answer but my application is crash at  this line  NSDictionary * dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:data error:&error];
 due to instruct of error ... whatever i don't know please help me