# How to get and parse JSON using objective C?

Tags: objective-c, json

Is it possible to get and parse JSON using objective C, then manipulate it within the cocoa framework for the iphone/pad? I'm specifically looking to do this for a couple of public APIs out there.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [Best JSON library to use when developing an iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: [how to do json parsing in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440534/how-to-do-json-parsing-in-iphone/5440615#5440615)

Basically, you should look into the TouchJSON library (with CJSONDeserializer and CJSONSerializer).

Answer (score 1):

Used [Json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) on some previous projects, worked really well.

**EDIT**: I read your post a bit too fast. I've used it on a Mac app before but not targeting the iphone/ipad. I *think* it should work but have no background to it. Maybe someone else can confirm?

Answer (score 1):

It's not only possible, it's dirt simple if you use one of the many existing open source projects dedicated to this task. I recommend trying [yajl-objc](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc), which offers a streaming parser, but [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) is a good one too. They're very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stay away from TouchJSON, since it gave me trouble a while back with special characters (line breaks) in strings.

However, I'll join the choir recommending [json-framework](http://github.com/stig/json-framework). Since I switched to that from TouchJSON everything's been running smoothly.

Regarding how to integrate the API in your project, they're equally simple to include and use.

As a side note, I'm just now testing out [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), since it's supposed to be much faster than both TouchJSON and json-framework. However, I can't vouch for its stability yet. The reviews of it are good, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an application that is only iOS 5.0 or later, you can use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).