# How to convert JSON data to Objects in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get and parse JSON using objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454454/how-to-get-and-parse-json-using-objective-c)

Recently I have discovered JSON can be used to send data to iPhone.

In my application there is lot of communication between the server so I construct lot of objects (classes) in various places.  Currently I am manually constructing my classes from the data I get from json.

Is there a framework or source code that does this conversion automatically after all we know object information we get from the service. I can pass the class structure and it will create a Array of those objects from json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Import the framework, send the JSON string `-[NSString JSONValue]` and you'll get back either an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray`.

Comment: I am already using http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/


Now this is returning NSDictionary or an NSArray. What I am doing now is manually processing contents of NSDictionary or an NSArray and initializing my own classes in this project. 


What I wanted to know is a way to automate that process also. For example after getting data related to persons  into NSArray, can I say “this is the structure of person class”, now give me NSArray of persons.