# How to convert JSON to Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I defined some custom classes, such as `Teacher`, `Student`...
Now I receive teacher info (JSON string) from remote server.

How can I convert the JSON string to `Teacher` object.

In Java, it's easy to implement a common method for all class (`Teacher`, `Student`...) with `reflect`.

But in Objective-C on iOS, the best way I can find is to use Entity of Core Data, which has `setValue:forKey` method. First I convert the JSON string to `NSDictionary`, the set the key-value pair in the disctionary to the `Entry`.

Is there any better ways?

(I'm from China, so maybe my English is poor, sorry!)

Comment: Your question was understandable, no worries :)

Comment: Have a look at this link[JSON TO OBJECT][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645703/how-to-convert-json-data-to-objects-in-iphone

Comment: Yes, I have already convert json string to NSDictionary. What I want is a common method to convert NSDictionary to my custom class. Andrian's answer is just it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all good frameworks for JSON parsing to dictionaries or other primitives, but if you're looking to avoid doing a lot of repetitive work, check out http://restkit.org . Specifically, check out https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md This is the example on Object mapping where you define mapping for your Teacher class and the json is automagically converted to a Teacher object by using KVC. If you use RestKit's network calls, the process is all transparent and simple, but I already had my network calls in place and what I needed was to convert my json response text to a User object (Teacher in your case) and I finally figured out how. If that's what you need, post a comment and I'll share how to do it with RestKit.

Note: I will assume the json is output using the mapped convention `{"teacher": { "id" : 45, "name" : "Teacher McTeacher"}}`. If it's not this way, but instead like this `{"id" : 45, "name" :  "Teacher McTeacher"}` then don't worry ... object mapping design doc in the link shows you how to do this...a few extra steps, but not too bad.

This is my callback from ASIHTTPRequest

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:[request.responseHeaders valueForKey:@"Content-Type"]]; // i'm assuming your response Content-Type is application/json
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *parsedData = [parser objectFromString:apiResponse error:&error];
    if (parsedData == nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR parsing api response with RestKit...%@", error);
        return;
    }

    [RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatterForString:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" inTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]; // This is handy in case you return dates with different formats that aren't understood by the date parser

    RKObjectMappingProvider *provider = [RKObjectMappingProvider new];

    // This is the error mapping provider that RestKit understands natively (I copied this verbatim from the RestKit internals ... so just go with it
    // This also shows how to map without blocks
    RKObjectMapping* errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
    [errorMapping mapKeyPath:@"" toAttribute:@"errorMessage"];
    [provider setMapping:errorMapping forKeyPath:@"error"];
    [provider setMapping:errorMapping forKeyPath:@"errors"];

    // This shows you how to map with blocks
    RKObjectMapping *teacherMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Teacher class] block:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"objectId"];
        [mapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    }];

    [provider setMapping:teacherMapping forKeyPath:@"teacher"];

    RKObjectMapper *mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:provider];
    Teacher *teacher = nil;
    RKObjectMappingResult *mappingResult = [mapper performMapping];
    teacher = [mappingResult asObject];

    NSLog(@"Teacher is %@ with id %lld and name %@", teacher, teacher.objectId, teacher.name);
}
```

You can obviously refactor this to make it cleaner, but that now solves all my problems.. no more parsing... just response -> magic -> Object

Comment: Thanks very much. It's just what I'm looking for. Go on please

Comment: Ok I updated my answer... this should get you going. Just make sure to follow the instructions to get RestKit into your project exactly as you see them on the RestKit github page. It took my about 30 minutes to get it into my project b/c of all the steps required, but now all my API calls are written quickly

Answer (score 6):

First, do you use JSON Parser? (if not, i'd recommend using SBJson).

Second, why not create an initWithDictionary init method in your custom class that returns self object?

Comment: Yes, I use SBJson to parse json string to NSDictionary. And I think it's an effective way to create an initWithDictionary method. But I have to create the method from all classes.

Comment: If you're using iOS 5 use the build in NSJSONSerialization class, if not use JSONKit, its faster than SBJSON.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, check out https://github.com/fanpyi/jsontooc/blob/master/README.md 
This is the example convert JSON data to Objective-C model, use nodejs.