# how to get JSON object from server as it (in the same order) iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ios7

Is there any way to get JSON object from the server in the same order??

For example when i fitch using browser my JSON object return like this:

```
{
"23": {
    "numberOfRecords": "3",
    "startDate": "27/11/2013",
    "endDate": "31/12/2014",
    "question": "How do you rate the new MenaME Portal ?",
    "voteScale": "5",
    "questions": {
        "option1": {
            "value": "1",
            "option": "Poor",
            "voteResult": "50.000"
        },
        "option2": {
            "value": "2",
            "option": "Acceptable",
            "voteResult": "0.000"
        },
        "option3": {
            "value": "3",
            "option": "Good",
            "voteResult": "0.000"
        },
        "option4": {
            "value": "4",
            "option": "Very Good",
            "voteResult": "0.000"
        },
        "option5": {
            "value": "5",
            "option": "Excellent",
            "voteResult": "50.000"
        }
    },
    "selectedAnswer": "0",
    "voteAnswered": "0",
    "votes": "6"
}
}
```

after parsing it with `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error]`

the object returned like this :

```
{
23 =     {
    endDate = "31/12/2014";
    numberOfRecords = 3;
    question = "How do you rate the new MenaME Portal ?";
    questions =         {
        option1 =             {
            option = Poor;
            value = 1;
            voteResult = "50.000";
        };
        option2 =             {
            option = Acceptable;
            value = 2;
            voteResult = "0.000";
        };
        option3 =             {
            option = Good;
            value = 3;
            voteResult = "0.000";
        };
        option4 =             {
            option = "Very Good";
            value = 4;
            voteResult = "0.000";
        };
        option5 =             {
            option = Excellent;
            value = 5;
            voteResult = "50.000";
        };
    };
    selectedAnswer = 0;
    startDate = "27/11/2013";
    voteAnswered = 0;
    voteScale = 5;
    votes = 6;
};
}
```

Is there any way or framework to get the object as it (in the same order returned from the server) ??

Comment: what do you mean same sort? you now have the parsed JSON, and `NSJSONSerialization` can do anything you need

Comment: What you have is what the server sent.  It's a set of NSDictionary objects that pretty much exactly maps the original JSON.  Yes, you can use something like restkit to materialize directly into custom objects, but that's a lot harder to deal with than the simple dictionary/array objects (which are often all you need).

Comment: @meda i mean the order of my data inside the object since when i get from the browser the first data is "numberOfRecords": "3", but after parsing in iPhone, the first data returned is endDate = "31/12/2014" which is wrong i need method or framework return my data in the same sort.
i need to view this data in the same order.

Comment: If you know all fields names then there are no a reason to have order the same as in incoming json

Comment: @nerowolfe i don't know the any field names :(

Comment: They will be vary from request to request? Or they will always be the same?  If the last case then just use the names that you are receiving now and the problem will be solved. The order of JSON dictionary result will always be random

Comment: (You know, if you'd answered @meda's question 11 hours ago you could have saved us all a lot of time.)  (And if you'd read the JSON spec at json.org you'd know there was no point in even asking the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries, both in JSON and NSDictionary, are unordered, meaning that it is irrelevant which order you see things in the log. This is defined in the JSON specification and the documentation for NSDictionary.

If it *actually* matters what order things are displayed in, then either the API you are linking to isn't using correct JSON, or you're doing something wrong in your app. To help with those situations you can use several of the sorted NSDictionary implementations that are around.

Comment: can you tell me examples of _sorted NSDictionary implementations_ ?

Comment: JSON dictionaries aren't unordered.  JSON is text, and text is ordered.

Comment: @simon - Have you read the JSON specification???  "An object is an *unordered* set of name/value pairs."

Comment: @Hot Licks They can specify whatever they want; once it's serialised into text, it has an order.

Comment: @Simon - And if you're dependent on that order you're not JSON-compliant, since the next JSON string could be in an entirely different order.

Comment: @ramzi - see L14M333's answer for an implementation.

Comment: @simon - see hot licks' replies for basically what I would have said. JSON dictionaries are certainly _not_ ordered. Or rather, the order is irrelevant and not part of the information that JSON transmits. JSON _arrays_ have an order, but dictionaries do not.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you want to ensure the dictionary is maintained in the correct order?

I understand in some cases (mine) an ancient JSON -> XML web service was being called by my app and the client refused to adjust the service so it could accept unordered JSON (valid json) but if you're writing the app, why do you need to ensure that it is in order?

I have a NSMutableDictionary subclass that keeps objects added by `setObject:forKey` in the order you call the method that can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/liamnichols/7869468).

It works by storing a `NSMutableOrderedSet` of keys within the dictionary and then overrides the [`keyEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keyEnumerator) method to return an enumerator based on the ordered set

```
- (NSEnumerator *)keyEnumerator
{
    return [self.orderedSetOfKeys objectEnumerator];
}
```

You could modify the `NSMutableDictionary` subclass i created to expose the `NSMutableOrderedSet` in the public header and then modify this set yourself to get an ordered version of your dictionary.. For example:

```
NSDictionary *JSONWebServiceDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

LNOrderedMutableDictionary *orderedDictionary = [[LNOrderedMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:JSONWebServiceDictionary];

NSMutableOrderedSet *order = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"key1",@"key2",@"key3"]]; //All the keys you are expecting and the order you want them in..

orderedDictionary.orderSet = order; //orderSet does not exist.. it is currently called `array` and not exposed in LNOrderedMutableDictionary.h
```

I haven't tested the code above but unless you want to create or modify an existing JSON parser then it seems that it is your only option..
If you did want to modify an existing parser then it might just be as simple as replacing dictionary instances with `LNOrderedMutableDictionary` to keep everything in order.

Another idea to expand the above sample code could be to replace

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *order = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"key1",@"key2",@"key3"]];
```

with an array returned in the `JSONWebServiceDictionary` dictionary as arrays keep their order when parsed from JSON so maybe you could do this?

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *order = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:[JSONWebServiceDictionary objectForKey:@"keyOrderArray"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you have.  If you test the result you got back from JSONObjectWithData (which we'll assume was declared as `id jsonObject`)

```
if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]) { ...
```

or

```
NSLog(@"The object type is %@", [jsonObject class]);
```

you will find that it is indeed an NSDictionary (or perhaps an NSMutableDictionary).  That dictionary, as you can see from the dump (or infer from the nearly identical JSON) contains a single entry with a key of "23".

So let's cast the jsonObject to an NSDictionary and reference it:

```
NSDictionary* jsonDict = (NSDictionary*) jsonObject;
NSDictionary* entry23Dict = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"23"];
```

Now, if you NSLog entry23Dict you will discover it contains all of the above, absent the `{ 23 = ... }` outermost dictionary.

You can then access, say, "questions" with

```
NSDictionary* questDict = [entry23Dict objectForKey:@"questions"];
```

From there the individual "option1", "option2", ... "option5" dictionaries can be accessed in a similar fashion.  You simply proceed one layer at a time -- don't get overwhelmed by the entire structure.  (It's often helpful, when you're first learning, to NSLog each "layer" as you "peel" it out of the containing structure.)

And, of course, you have all the standard facilities that are available to NSDictionary objects (and NSArray objects, should your JSON contain any `[..]` arrays).  For instance, you can iterate on the keys of the dictionary with

```
for (NSString* key in jsonDict) {
    NSLog(@"This entry's number is %@", key);  // For the above will print "23"
    NSDictionary* numberedDict = jsonDict[key];  // Using the "new" form of dictionary access
    NSString* endDate = numberedDict[@"endDate"];  // Ditto
    NSLog(@"The end date is %@", endDate);
}
```

Comment: My friend getting the object is not my problem, My problem is the sort of my data inside the object since when i get from the browser the first data is `"numberOfRecords": "3",` but after parsing in iPhone, the first data returned is `endDate = "31/12/2014"` which is wrong i need method or framework return my data in the same sort.

Comment: @ramzishadid - Read json.org.  The order of entries in an "object" is not defined and can vary from one JSON string to the next.  There is no JSON toolkit (not even in Java) that will change this fact.  If you need items in a certain order, fetch them from the dictionary in that order.

Answer (score -1):

This is a fairly common problem.  It's also probably the most annoying part about iOS.  (java doesn't have this issue at all).  If you want to get back objects, take a look at restkit.org  Specifically this answer may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284343/836450

Comment: What's "annoying"?  JSON is very easy to understand if one approaches it simply, vs getting all involved in something like restkit prematurely.  The "common problem" is that most people are looking for a cookbook, and there is none with JSON, since every situation is different.

Comment: It's annoying because in jackson / java you always get models back.  With iOS you are forced to write methods to manually map NSDictionarys back to your models.  It's unneeded busy work.  restkit is the only good solution, but not many people use it.

Comment: But folks learn Jackson (which is not a "part" of Java) and are clueless as to how to handle anything that doesn't map neatly.  And you have to learn the complexities of Jackson before you can begin, when in Objective-C you're off and running with a ten minute tutorial.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from.  In my expirence with multi platform projects (ie an "app" with iOS, android and web versions) iOS tends to be the hardest to maintain.  If a model changes through the system iOS takes the most effort to keep in sync.  I guess it depends on your perspective as to which is better

Comment: And how is this going to help the OP, since he doesn't know the field names?

Comment: Lol actually re-reading this about 5 times I think OP is concerned that members of an object are returned in a different order.

Comment: Yeah, the order of members in an "object" is "undefined" by specification (and for good reason).  I've never known that to cause any real problem -- folks just need to get over it.