# How to parse following JSON string in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios4

I have JSON string of following format, which need to be parsed in objective-c

```
[{"image":"<link_to_image>",
  "pic-number":"2862",
  "n-lines":5,
  "default":"[{"line_1":"one!"},
              {"line_2":"two"},
              {"line_3":"three"},
              {"line_4":"four"},
              {"line_5":"five"}]"
}, 
... ]
```

The length of default array may vary for each item.

Comment: And accept your answer if you got the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the cause of the problem,

Instead

```
  "default":**"**[{"line_1":"one!"},
              {"line_2":"two"},
              {"line_3":"three"},
              {"line_4":"four"},
              {"line_5":"five"}]**"**
```

The JSON string should has following format otherwise the parsing will fail

```
  "default":[{"line_1":"one!"},
              {"line_2":"two"},
              {"line_3":"three"},
              {"line_4":"four"},
              {"line_5":"five"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `TouchJSON` which is available in:

http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/

And also go through these

[How to use touch json and sbjson](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/how-to-use-touch-json-and-sbjson/)

[how to do json parsing in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440534/how-to-do-json-parsing-in-iphone)

[How to parse JSON into Objective C - SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919249/how-to-parse-json-into-objective-c-sbjson)